# JS/Jquery won't work until page reload in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reload

I've googled around and hear it has to do with AJAX. If so, how do I turn it off, or still have it for my layout and still have my javascript working? I made a simple slider that won't work if you go back to a page from another unless you reload the page. Help!

Comment: You can just remove the Turbolinks gem. It's usually easy to fix changing jquery's on load callback to a tubolinks event, but I'd recommend to read Turbolinks readme and decide if you really want to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I really don't have a need for turbolinks tbh and kinda knew they were the culprit, but needed confirmation. I'm fairly new to web development so Stackoverflow is definitely my best friend. Lol. I'll make some changes to the app and update my feedback on how it went and maybe you can change your comment to an answer. I almost have enough reputation where I could upvote it! haha

Comment: Yeah you're right. I just removed the //= require turbolinks from my application.js and problem solved. Yay! Stupid turbolinks.

Comment: Hahaha, it's not stupid, read the Turbolinks readme on github, personally I like it.